# Can't install ElementaryOS on DELL XPS 15 (9650)

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, boot, uefi

I've just got a new Dell XPS 15 (9650) with Windows 10 on it, but I want to install ElementaryOS (https://elementary.io) as the only OS (so I want to remove Windows). I created a bootable USB with Rufus and set is as default boot option in the BIOS.

The screen that i get is this:

[image]
If I choose the option "Install elementary OS" I get a new screen with the E logo and nothing else. I've search this problem on the internet and I found out that it is related to the UEFI, so I found this article on Dell website (http://www.dell.com/support/article/it/it/itbsdt1/sln297060/xps-13-9343--how-to-install-ubuntu-developer-edition-1404-on-a-dell-pc-configured-for-the-unified-extensible-firmware-interface--uefi--bios?lang=en) that explains step by step what you need to do in order to install Ubuntu on the PC, but nothing.

I tried to remove the secure boot, to switch from "RAID on" to "AHCI" in the Sata Operation panel of the bios, uncheck "Enable Legacy Option ROMs" in the Advanced Boot Options panel, and create a new option in the boot sequence with grubx64.efi as the filename (tried also with BOOTx64.efi, but nothing).

All I get is the same screen with the E logo.

This is my current configuration (after lots of tries) of the BIOS:

> Boot Sequence:
>
> 1. *My USB key with Elementary*
> 2. *The boot option I created with "\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.EFI" as the file name*
> 3. Windows disk
>
> Advanced Boot Options:
>
> 1. Enable Legacy Option ROMs **unchecked**
> 2. Enable Attempt Legacy Boot **unchecked**
> 3. Enable UEFI Network Stack **checked**
>
> UEFI Boot Path Security: "Always, Except Internal HDD" (possible other values: "Always" and "Never")
>
> Sata Operation: "RAID On" (possible other values: "Disabled" and "AHCI")
>
> Secure Boot: Enabled Fastboot: "Auto" (possible other values: "Minimal" and "Thorough")

My BIOS version is 1.5 I've read that you can start the OS installation with a nomodeset parameter, but it seems like it's not the proper solution.

Please, if you know, tell me what I need to change. 
Thank you very much

Comment: i have same probleme what is solution please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up launching the OS installation with nomodeset as a parameter. After installing it I couldn't reboot/shutdown the pc, so I edited the grub file (`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`) and changed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` value to `nomodeset`. Now it works nicely.

Comment: The "nomodeset" allows me to begin elementaryos but then does not scale on Dell XPS 15 (4K). Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I think this is a partial solution, it enables you to install the graphics drivers you need. Then you shouldn't need nomodeset anymore.

Comment: I know it's not the best solution... Tonight I'll try the solution suggested by George Barbaz, which seems the most accurate, and if that works I'll change the accepted answer to his.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell laptop as well (Inspiron) and I have two suggestions. First try the "try" elementary option to see if you can get into the OS, then install once you are in. Second, I had to disable UEFI and secure boot and enable Legacy boot.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work... the "try" option gives me the same result, while by enabling the legacy boot (I already have UEFI and secure boot disabled), it does not even ask me if I want to try the OS or install it directly, and I get the usual screen with the logo

Answer (score 0):

damn ... my exact environment ... and i cannot remember how i got it working ... putting this here so I have a placeholder for when i get my BIOS configuration

I remember that the hardest parts was getting it to boot correctly and getting the docking station with two additional monitors set up ... checking

Comment: adding new answer for my values

Answer (score 0):

running Loki in same machine
see if this helps

BIOS setting
Boot Order
    Diskette, USB Storage, CD/DVD, NIC, M.2 PCIe SSD

Boot options
     LEGACY not UEFI

Adv boot options
     Enable Legacy boot ROMs

SATA
     RAID on

Then after booting

installed
     Intel Microcode and
     NVidea-384

for grub ... I am NOT running nomodeset ... that normally seems to work when you are having issues with monitors
but I did take quiet out

Just from memory ... i think I remember that there was an issue with the M.2 PCIe SSD ... but cannot remember where i read it

I know ... I should have taken notes ... sue me ... I am the only non windows user here at work and I needed to get it working ASAP

Comment: I've read a lot of threads that say that for linux you should select AHCI instead of RAID on... Anoyhow I'll try to do what you suggested, since nomode set has been giving me a lot of problem

Comment: Unfortunately it keeps beeing stuck at the logo